# How do i specify a neighborhood around a node and then search for points within that neighborhood?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

This might be a bit long but would be interesting to see if you exercise some patience.

Consider that I have the image below.
[image]

**Allvectors** is a cell array containing the vector points (edges) around the north(n), south(s), east(e), and west(w) faces (see the points where there is an arrow or an ‘X’ mark) of each internal node.

**Contactpoints** (shown in red dot) are nodes that contains both 1, 2, and 3 pixel labels as its neighbours.

**xpoint1** is a cell array containing all vectors at each face of all contactpoints.

An x-point1 is a face that has adjacent pixels of labels 1 and 2 such that the vector direction is either ‘A+’, or ‘A-‘ depending on the direction of label 2. This is same for pixel labels 3 and 2, such that the vector direction is either ‘B+’ or ‘B-‘.

**What I have tried so far:**

I have been able to find as many x-points as I want and the code runs successfully. However, the way I am doing it looks quite cumbersome in the sense that I keep re-writing the procedure for each new x-point that is to be found and this results in too many functions and variables. Also, this makes me find the same number of x-points for both ‘A’ and ‘B’ vectors, whereas, I have realized the number of x-points need not necessarily be the same.

**See code below:**

```
clc; clear; close all;

Img = [3 3 3 2 2 
       3 3 3 2 2 
       3 1 2 2 2 
       1 1 2 2 2 
       1 1 1 1 2];

%%%%%% Plot the image
figure, imshow(Img, [], 'InitialMagnification','fit')   
grid on; 
hold on;

%# Find the size of the image   
[row, col] = size(Img);

%# Obtain total no. of internal x and y node points
ny = row - 1;  nx = col - 1;

%%%%%%%%%%% Obtain full output grids 
[gridy, gridx] = meshgrid(1:ny, 1:nx); 
coords = [gridy(:), gridx(:)];

%%%%%%%% Obtain node counts
nodecount = nx*(coords(:,1)-1) + coords(:,2);

%%%%%%%%%%% Compute the vectors around each node
%%%%% firstly create a cell array to store your vectors
Allvectors = cell(ny*nx, 4);
for nodecount = 1:ny*nx;

    %%%%%% determine the x and y-coords of each node
    [node_y, node_x] = get_xycoord_from_nodecount(nx, nodecount);

    %%%%%% compute vectors at each face around each node
    [n, s, e, w] = find_vectors(node_y, node_x, Img);

    Allvectors{nodecount,1} = n;
    Allvectors{nodecount,2} = s;
    Allvectors{nodecount,3} = e;
    Allvectors{nodecount,4} = w;

end

%%%%%%% Determine the contactpoint nodes
cpNodes = find(( any(strcmp('A+', Allvectors),2) | any(strcmp('A-', Allvectors),2)) & (any(strcmp('B+', Allvectors),2) | any(strcmp('B-', Allvectors),2)))


%%%%%%% find the node as well as coordinates of the contactpoints
nodecount        = cpNodes;
[node_y, node_x] = get_xycoord_from_nodecount(nx, nodecount);


%%%%%%% find all other x-points around cp
%# extract vectors for all x-points for pixel label 1
xpoint1 = Allvectors(cpNodes,:);  

%# create an empty cell array wherein the vectors around the faces of each new node will be stored
xpt2_labelA = cell(numel(cpNodes), 4);
xpt3_labelA = cell(numel(cpNodes), 4);

for ii = 1: numel(cpNodes)

    %# COMPUTATIONS FOR pixel label 1
    %%%%%% Determine the face where the 1st x-point (i.e. x-point1) lies
    Idx1_labelA(ii,:) = find(strcmp('A+', xpoint1(ii,:)) | strcmp('A-', xpoint1(ii,:)))


    %%%%%% Determine the face where the 2nd x-point (i.e. x-point2) lies
    %# firstly find the next Node from the previous   
    [xpt2_labelA, a, node_Anext] = find_node_next(ii, nodecount, nx, Idx1_labelA, xpt2_labelA, Allvectors);

    %%%%%% find all possible face(s) where x-point2 lies for both Solid phase
    if find(strcmp('A+', xpt2_labelA(ii,:)) | strcmp('A-', xpt2_labelA(ii,:))) > 0
         Idx2_labelA(ii,:)   = find(strcmp('A+', xpt2_labelA(ii,:)) | strcmp('A-', xpt2_labelA(ii,:)));
    else
        continue  
    end


    %%%%%% Determine the face where the 3rd x-point (i.e. x-point2) lies
         % repeat the steps for x-point2, however, rename the indices and cell
         % arrays with 2 or 3 where appropriate



    %# COMPUTATIONS FOR pixel label 3
    %%%%%% Determine the face where the 1st x-point (i.e. x-point1) lies
    Idx1_labelB(ii,:) = find(strcmp('B+', xpoint1(ii,:)) | strcmp('B-', xpoint1(ii,:)));



    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% COLLATE vectors from all X-Points found:
    %# Average unit vector 'A'
    Va = [(ya1 + ya2 +... yan)/Na, (xa1 + xa2 +... xan)/Na];  % Na=total no. of X-points collated for vector A within the specified neighborhood.

    %# Average unit vector 'B'
    Vb = [(yb1 + yb2 +... ybn)/Nb, (xb1 + xb2 +... xbn)/Nb];  % Nb=total no. of X-points collated for vector B within the specified neighborhood.
     %where: ya, yb, xa, xb are components of the vectors in the directions observed
     %as an example: from the arrow shown, ya1=0, and xa1=1

    %%%%%%%%% Compute angle between average unit vectors A and B
    angle(ii) = 180 - ( acos( dot(Va(ii,:), Vb(ii,:)) / (norm(Va(ii,:)) *    norm(Vb(ii,:)) ) ) * 180/pi );
    angle(:, ii) = angle(ii); 


end
```

**functions:**

```
function[node_y, node_x] = get_xycoord_from_nodecount(nx, nodecount)
%This function obtains the x and y coordinates from nodecount

node_x = mod(nodecount - 1, nx) + 1;
node_y = (nodecount - node_x)/nx + 1;

end





function [n, s, e, w] = find_vectors(node_y, node_x, Img)
%This function determines if a vector exists at the north, south,
%east and western faces around each node. 

%If a normal vector exists at any of these faces, 
%the function determines if it is an 'A+', 'A-', 'B+', or a 'B-'
%
%Where '+/-' is for +ve or -ve x or y-direction, and 'A' or 'B' tells if it
%is a vector resulting from a pixel labels 1|2,  or 3|2

n = NaN; s = NaN; e = NaN; w = NaN;

%# NORTH FACE
if Img(node_y, node_x + 1) == 2
    if Img(node_y, node_x) == 1
        n = 'A+'; 
    elseif Img(node_y, node_x) == 3
        n = 'B+';    
    end
elseif Img(node_y, node_x) == 2
    if Img(node_y, node_x + 1) == 1
        n = 'A-';
    elseif Img(node_y, node_x + 1) == 3
        n = 'B-';
    end
end


%# SOUTH FACE
if Img(node_y + 1, node_x + 1) == 2
    if Img(node_y + 1, node_x) == 1
        s = 'A+';
    elseif Img(node_y + 1, node_x) == 3
        s = 'B+'; 
    end
elseif Img(node_y + 1, node_x) == 2
    if Img(node_y + 1, node_x + 1) == 1
        s = 'A-';
    elseif Img(node_y + 1, node_x + 1) == 3
        s = 'B-';
    end
end


%# EAST FACE
if Img(node_y + 1, node_x + 1) == 2
    if Img(node_y, node_x + 1) == 1
        e = 'A+';
    elseif Img(node_y, node_x + 1) == 3
        e = 'B+';
    end
elseif Img(node_y, node_x + 1) == 2
    if Img(node_y + 1, node_x + 1) == 1
        e = 'A-';
    elseif Img(node_y + 1, node_x + 1) == 3
        e = 'B-';
    end
end


%# WEST FACE
if Img(node_y + 1, node_x) == 2
    if Img(node_y, node_x) == 1
        w = 'A+';
    elseif Img(node_y, node_x) == 3
        w = 'B+';
    end
elseif Img(node_y, node_x) == 2
    if Img(node_y + 1, node_x) == 1
        w = 'A-';
    elseif Img(node_y + 1, node_x) == 3
        w = 'B-';
    end
end



end





function [xpt2_labelA, a, node_Anext] = find_node_next(ii, nodecount, nx, Idx1_labelA, xpt2_labelA, Allvectors)


if Idx1_labelA(ii,:) == 1    %# xpoint1 lies on the north face
    %%%%% Find the node at the northern end of the face which contains xpoint1
    node_Anext(ii,:) =  nodecount(ii,:) - nx;

    %%%%%% extract the n, s, e, w faces from AllNormalvectors
    a = Allvectors(node_Anext(ii,:),:);

    %%%%%% store the new results (exclude the existing result at the southern face of the node northofCP)
    xpt2_labelA{ii,1} = a{1};
    xpt2_labelA{ii,2} = NaN;
    xpt2_labelA{ii,3} = a{3};
    xpt2_labelA{ii,4} = a{4};

elseif Idx1_labelA(ii,:) == 2    %# xpoint1 lies on the south face
    %%%%% Find the node at the southern end of the face which contains xpoint1
    node_Anext(ii,:) = nodecount(ii,:) + nx;

    %%%%%% extract n, s, e, w faces from AllNormalvectors
    a = Allvectors(node_Anext(ii,:),:);

    %%%%%% store the new results (exclude the node at the northern face of the node southofCP)
    xpt2_labelA{ii,1} = NaN;
    xpt2_labelA{ii,2} = a{2};
    xpt2_labelA{ii,3} = a{3};
    xpt2_labelA{ii,4} = a{4};

elseif Idx1_labelA(ii,:) == 3      %# xpoint1 lies on the east face
    %%%%% Find the node at the eastern end of the face which contains xpoint1
    node_Anext(ii,:)  = nodecount(ii,:) + 1;

    %%%%%% extract n, s, e, w faces from AllNormalvectors
    a = Allvectors(node_Anext(ii,:),:);

    %%%%%% store the new results (exclude the node at the western face of the node eastofCP)
    xpt2_labelA{ii,1} = a{1};
    xpt2_labelA{ii,2} = a{2};
    xpt2_labelA{ii,3} = a{3};
    xpt2_labelA{ii,4} = NaN;

elseif Idx1_labelA(ii,:) == 4      %# xpoint1 lies on the west face
    %%%%% Find the node at the western end of the face which contains xpoint1
    node_Anext(ii,:)  = nodecount(ii,:) - 1;

    %%%%%% extract n, s, e, w faces from AllNormalvectors
    a = Allvectors(node_Anext(ii,:),:);

    %%%%%% store the new results (exclude the node at the eastern face of the node westofCP)
    xpt2_labelA{ii,1} = a{1};
    xpt2_labelA{ii,2} = a{2};
    xpt2_labelA{ii,3} = NaN;
    xpt2_labelA{ii,4} = a{4};

end
end
```

Going forward, what I would want is to specify a neighbourhood (eg: see dashed red line in the figure) around each cpNodes, and then find all x-points within that neighbourhood as well as collate them.

Results obtained from my example image above would be as follows:
[image]

from the figure, we can observe that:

```
%there are 3 x-points for Vector A (pixels 1|2), hence,
ya1 = 0, ya2 = 0, ya3 = -1
xa1 = +1, xa2 = +1, xa3 = 0

%also, there are 4 x-points for Vector B (pixels 3|2)
yb1 = +1, yb2 = +1, yb3 = 0, yb4 = 0
xb1 = 0, xb2 = 0, xb3 = +1, xb4 = +1

%average vector A:
Va = [(ya1 + ya2 + ya3)/3, (xa1 + xa2 + xa3)/3];
   %ans: 
   Va = [-1/3, 2/3]

%average vector B:
Vb = [(yb1 + yb2 + yb3 + yb4)/4, (xb1 + xb2 + xb3 + xb4)/4];
   %ans: 
   Vb = [0.5, 0.5]

%angle between A and B:
angle = 180 - ( acos( dot(Va, Vb) / (norm(Va) * norm(Vb) ) ) * 180/pi )
   %ans:
   angle = 108.4349
```

Honestly, I have no idea how to go about this - which is why I need help here.
Many thanks for your anticipated help/suggestions/advice on this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have a feeling I've seen this question before. What is the desired output for your sample input? Is your `A+`, `B-` labeling a part of the output, or is it just a means to achieve the final result?

Comment: Thank you @Beaker. A+ and its likes are means to achieve the final result. They are unit normal vectors in the specified + or - directions. I will collate them for A and B, and then use the dot product to obtain angle between.

Comment: The final output is the angle between the two vectors A and B. What I will do after collating the x-points is to obtain an average unit normal vector for all the x-points collated for each A and B vectors. In the diagram above for example, the first x-point for `A` has a vector `[y1, x1] = [0, 1];` the 2nd x-point marked 'X' in red, has a vector `[y2, x2] = [0, 1];`, and the last x-point has the vector `[y3, x3] = [-1, 0];` I will compute the average of these vectors collated, and will do this also for `B` and then otbain the angle between them using the dot product.

Comment: I actually was trying to make the question as simple as possible so that someone can grasp the post as quickly as possible.  Nonetheless, i will look to see what other bits i could add to make it clearer. Thank you so much.

Comment: I have made an edit in which i have added the final output to the code. The expected output is the **angle** between vectors `A and B`. `Allvectors` (see its meaning just after the figure above) though obtained from the input image is not necessarily an output; it is only a means to achieving the final output.

Comment: As to comparing the input and output, you can do that by visually observing the image. For instance, if you look at the specified neighborhood (red dashed line around the contactpoint), you can tell how many x-points are possible for both `A (3 x-points) and B (4 x-points)`, you can also tell the vector direction at each x-point. I hope this makes sense?

Comment: @beaker: please calm down. I have added the expected result from my sample image.  Please let me know if you still need more clarifications. Thank you for your time.